# psych - Getting factor loadings as data.frame for LaTeX export

Tags: r, latex, psych, factor-analysis

I am using the `psych` package's `fa` command for factor analysis, and so have an object of class `fa`. I can query the loadings with `fac$loadings`, but I want to only extract the table containing the loadings, so I can use `xtable` (or similar) to convert it into LaTeX format.

Example code:

```
library(psych)
library(xtable)
data(bfi)
fac <- fa(r=cor(bfi, use="complete.obs"), nfactors=5, fm="ml", rotate="none")
fac$loadings
ld <- someMagicalFunction(fac$loadings)
xtable(ld)
```

Can anyone tell me what I can use for `someMagicalFunction`?

Comment: `fac <- fa(r=cor(bfi), nfactors=5, fm="ml", rotate="none")` gives me a lot of error messages (e.g., `Something is seriously wrong the correlation matrix.`) and does not produce anything.

Comment: @Henrik apologies, should be fixed now. Needed to add `use="complete.obs"` to `cor`.

Comment: Actually, just say fa(bfi,nfactors=5, fm="ml",rotate="none").  That will find the pairwise correlation matrix without needing to do it your self.  As of version 1.3.10.11, fa will take the use parameter if you want to specify use="complete".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you look at `fac$loading`, you see that it is a S3 object. Removing the class attribute gives you a `matrix` which can then be passed to `xtable`:

```
str(fac$loadings)
class(fac$loadings)

xtable(unclass(fac$loadings))
```

Comment: This command works to get the actual loadings matrix, but how can you capture the bottom half of the print.loadings() command, which gives the SS loadings and the Proportion and cumulative Variance?

Comment: Please specify the package from which you're calling `xtable()` from.

Comment: @sunitprasad1 library `xtable` as specified in the question.

Answer (score 6):

That works fine.

An alternative is to use the fa2latex function in psych:

Using your example:

```
library(psych)
fac <- fa(bfi,5)
fa2latex(fac)
```

will give you an APA ready LaTeX table.

Bill

Answer (score 0):

The result of xtable is in HTML language.
If you want to save it as a file, you can use:

```
print.xtable(x, type="HTML", file="table.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to call `fac$Vaccounted` that will pull the proportional variance, cumulative variance, etc that can then be put into a df or kable object:

```
fac$Vaccounted %>% kable()
```

Do the same with `fac$weights` to access the loadings:

```
fac$weights
```

That should cover all the output you needed.